Merge videos on computer automatically
I have some videos regularly downloaded to my computer, these are short videos, around 10-15 seconds each. I usually use https://online-video-cutter.com/merge-videos to merge them, and it serves my purpose well. I just drag and drop the videos I want and hit the download button without any additional steps.
My goal is to automate this process, so I thought I could merge the videos locally on my computer using ffmpeg. I've tried with JavaScript libraries like ffmpeg-static and ffmpeg-fluent, but I couldn't get the desired result; I keep encountering an error.
What I want is automation of this process. How can I achieve this? What can I use and how? I attribute my inability to accomplish this to myself since what I want seems quite simple. Thank you in advance. Below, I'm leaving the JavaScript code I tried, but it gives me an error: 'ffmpeg exited with code 234: Error opening output file ./merged-video.mp4. Error opening output files: Invalid argument.'
The number of videos is not fixed; if an example is needed, let's say the first 30 files under a folder.
The videos are in mp4 format, and their frame sizes vary
I don't have much knowledge about videos, but other things could be different too, not just the frame sizes. The website I shared above handles all of these somehow. It's a bit off-topic, but is it possible to learn how the process on the mentioned website works(look at the source code somehow, Idk)?
If there's any other way to automatically merge these videos, I would appreciate it if you could share it.
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg')

function mergeVideos(folderPath, outputFile) {
  fs.readdir(folderPath, (err, files) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Error:', err)
      return
    }

    const videoFiles = files.filter((file) => {
      const ext = path.extname(file).toLowerCase()
      return ext === '.mp4'
    })

    const command = ffmpeg().outputOptions('-movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov')
    videoFiles.forEach((file) => {
      command.input(path.join(folderPath, file))
    })

    command.on('error', (err) => {
      console.error('ffmpeg error:', err.message)
    })

    command.on('end', () => {
      console.log('merged')
    })

    command
      .complexFilter(
        '[0:v]scale=w=1920:h=1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease[v0];[1:v]scale=w=1920:h=1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease[v1];[v0][v1]hstack=inputs=2[v]'
      )
      .outputOptions('-map', '[v]')
    command.mergeToFile(outputFile, folderPath)
  })
}

const folderPath = '../../upload-videos/1/2'
const outputFile = './merged-video.mp4'
mergeVideos(folderPath, outputFile)

